# My stop-and-go GUI - should I just reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Perfect Example: I typed the title question in its field, and it appeared there - over five seconds later.

This has been going on for about a month. When I play a board game online, I can make a move, and hear the sound right away, and hear my opponent's response move! But my screen may not even show my move for a long time. It comes and goes, but recurs after a minute at most. The GUI (except the mouse cursor) just hangs for a few seconds repeatedly.

terminal and gedit operate flawlessly, as fast as ever.

I use an old Nvidia GeForce 310 graphics card (GT218) in an Optiplex 755 running Ubuntu 16.04. It drives two monitors with a 3x3 array of virtual desktops. None of that has changed in over a year of happy computing. The card has been used in Ubuntu machines for many years.

The "top" command shows that the load average is consistently under 2.0, there is 8 GB of RAM with half of it free, and no obvious heavy CPU users.

```
top - 14:08:05 up  1:03,  1 user,  load average: 0.39, 0.35, 0.35
Tasks: 251 total,   1 running, 199 sleeping,   0 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.2 us, 13.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.1 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8036804 total,  5037380 free,  1494072 used,  1505352 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16046076 total, 16046076 free,        0 used.  6086400 avail Mem
```

I think this started at the time of some updates a few weeks ago, in December 2019.

A Google search and a search here didn't turn up other people with the same problem recently.

My video driver is "nouveau" .

A power-down, rest, boot sequence didn't help.

So I am torn between trying a different video driver, or, re-installing Ubuntu, or, replacing the video card. What would you do?

Diagnostics:

```
sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] [10de:0a66] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Pegatron GT218 [GeForce 310] [1b0a:9060]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc80 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel

h-OptiPlex-755:~$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218 [GeForce 310] [10DE:A66]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:dc80(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

h-OptiPlex-755:~$  glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: NVA8
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Install Nvidia driver. System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Comment: It offered: Using Nvidia binary driver - version 340.107 from nvidia-340 (proprietary, tested)  .  and :

Using Nvidia legacy binary driver - version 304.135 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)   .  I chose the first one, it works great!  TY TY.  Make it an answer and i will pick it. BTW I was surprised at the number of pages recommending complicated procedures to install nvidia's drivers.

Comment: i posted too soon! With the 340.107 driver, the stop-and-start continues in Chrome. Less often, I think. I also tried an AMD card 5750 card with more memory; similar problem continues with it. (I will probably revert to the old card until I get something that the AMD Catalysts driver supports.)

Comment: Correction , its a 7570 card, but still too old for Catalyst driver.

Comment: Later updates made the problem less frequent. Booting into Windows shows that the hardware is working. (But I won't use Windows at all right now, because the "NSA-Crypt" update fails to install on it, and I won't run Windows with insecure crypto. Typical Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

Install Nvidia driver 340 from

System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Comment: Nvidia driver didn't change it.